# Give an example of a finite nonabelian group whose exponent and order are equal

Tags: group-theory

My first thoughts were to have equivalence classes modulo a number that all equal to 1 when brought to a power, but wouldn't that make it abelian? I'm kind of stuck and can't really think of much else.

Comment: The symmetric group $S_3$ works.

Answer (score 2):

The smallest example would appear to be $S_3$.  The exponent is $6$, the same as the order.

Then you could consider semi-direct products, like $\Bbb Z_5\rtimes\Bbb Z_2$.  That's the dihedral group.

Come to think of it, any dihedral group $D_{2p}$, with $p\ne2$ prime, will fit the bill.